# Create copies of files in same directory

Tags: shell, cp

Lets say I have a directory with the following files:

```
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

I want to copy these and basically paste in the same directory making new files eg:

```
1.txt 1(1).txt 2.txt 2(1).txt 3.txt 3(1).txt
```

This is harder than I thought! This seems trivial on Windows, just highlight a bunch of files, copy/paste, and it creates the same files but adds 'Copy' into the name.

Comment: The Windows trick also works on some file browsers like Nautilus and Nemo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In plain Unix style you’d need to loop over the files:

```
for file in 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt; do cp -pi "$file" "${file%.*}(1).txt"; done
```

`${file%.*}` removes the extension from the filename, then `(1).txt` adds the number and restores the extension. The options to `cp` prompt if a target already exists (`-i`) and preserve permissions (`-p`).

Most Linux systems will have the `mmv` package available; that allows you to simply do

```
mcp '*.txt' '#1(1).txt'
```

This copies every file ending in `.txt` to a new file, matching the first wildcard (`#1`) and appending `(1).txt`. The parentheses don’t need escaping here because they’re within quotes.

Alternatively, if you use a graphical file manager, you can do exactly the same as you would in Windows.

Comment: It would make sense to check first whether the target file name already exists (e.g. if the code is run twice accidentally).

Answer (score 1):

> This seems trivial on Windows, just highlight a bunch of files

I thing it is trivial in various GUI file managers in Linux too, but you need shell solution, right? Here it is:

```
for F in *; do cp -p "$F" "${F%.*}\(1\).${F#*.}"; done
```

`${F%.*}` extracts part of filename before dot, while `${F#*.}` extracts extension.

Comment: `${F#*.}` will fail if there is more than one dot in the file name.

Answer (score 1):

```
set ./*.txt
while    [ -e "$1" ] || [ -L "$1" ]
do       case ${1##*(} in ($1|*[!0-9]*\)|\)*)
         cp "$1" "${1%.*}(1).txt";;
         (*\)*) set "${1##*(}" "$@"; cp \
         "$2" "${2%"$1"}$((${1%)*}+1))).txt"
         shift;; esac
shift;   done
```

That should handle all cases pretty well, I think. It will increment the *(copy)* number if necessary - but will otherwise just insert a *(1)* between the extension and the file name.

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`, wildcard move or copy is shipped with the shell:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -C '(*).txt' '$1 (1).txt'
```

But I would really advise against using a space in a filename for this purpose, and parentheses are also not ideal. I mention this because every time I encounter a pattern like this (for instance `x.txt` and `x (1).txt` and `x (2).txt`) and want to do tab completion without double quotes, I have to write `x <tab> <backslash> <space> <backslash> ( 1 <tab>` to get it right. Also, it looks confusing in `ls` output because it's not really clear where the filenames end. I'd use `x.txt`, `x.1.txt` and `x.2.txt`. This way, the filenames visually apear as single units, and this completion works: `x <tab> .1 <tab>`.